# compile vlc-android not working - iconv not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, vlc, iconv

I am trying to compile vlc-android from source acording to this manual. [AndroidCompile](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/)

I'm getting this error:

```
  CC       src/smb_utils.lo
src/smb_utils.c:32:19: fatal error: iconv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <iconv.h>
               ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [src/smb_utils.lo] Error 1
```

And at the end this:

```
checking for iconv... no, consider installing GNU libiconv
configure: error: iconv() not found
make: *** [.zvbi] Error 1
contribs: make failed
```

The weird thing is that it workied fine yesterday.
Im using Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: same error here this morning (Ubuntu 15.10)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution (workaround actually).
Problem is that android patch for iconv (`contrib/src/iconv/libiconv-android-ios.patch`) fails to apply. It is already applied in iconv version 1.14

Temporary workaround is to comment out patch applying for android. It is on line 26 of `contrib/src/iconv/rules.mak`